# How do I create a list that includes the mapped input and output lists of a function?

Tags: python, list

I have a python function that takes in a list of `countries` and returns a list of `languages`.  Something like this:

```
languages = []
for i in countries[:]:
    languages.append(function(i))
print(languages)
```

How do I output a table of countries & languages correctly mapped to each other based on the output of that function? Assuming the output is always 1 language per country. Something like this:

```
germany          germany
yemen            arabic
france           french
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `OrderedDict`, because that would be the most idiomatic way of storing key-value mappings. Use `str.format` to print formatted output in a neat tabulated format.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

o = OrderedDict.fromkeys(countries)
for k in o:
    o[k] = function(o[k])

for k, v in o.items():
    print('{:>10s}\t{:>10s}'.format(k, v))
```

---

```
   germany      german
     yemen      arabic
    france      french
```